# TableRow not being displayed in TableLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Can anyone see what is wrong with the below:

```
                if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == 3){
                TableLayout tbl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tblHistory);

                if (tbl.getChildCount() != mExceptions.size()){

                    for (int i = tbl.getChildCount(); i < mExceptions.size(); i++){
                        GPSException e = mExceptions.get(i);

                        //TableRow
                        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
                        tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

                        //DateTime
                        TextView tx = new TextView(this);
                        tx.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        tx.setText(e.DateTime);
                        tx.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), android.R.attr.textAppearanceMedium);
                        tx.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        tx.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                        tr.addView(tx);

                        //Speed
                        tx = new TextView(this);
                        tx.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        tx.setText(Float.toString(e.Speed));
                        tx.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), android.R.attr.textAppearanceMedium);
                        tx.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        tx.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                        tr.addView(tx);

                        //Bearing
                        tx = new TextView(this);
                        tx.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        tx.setText(Double.toString(e.Degrees));
                        tx.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), android.R.attr.textAppearanceMedium);
                        tx.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        tx.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                        tr.addView(tx);

                        //Exceptions
                        tx = new TextView(this);
                        tx.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        tx.setText(e.ExceptionString());
                        tx.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), android.R.attr.textAppearanceMedium);
                        tx.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        tx.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                        tr.addView(tx);

                        tbl.addView(tr, 0);
                    }

                    tbl.invalidate();
                    tbl.refreshDrawableState();
                }
            }
```

My class implements LocationListener and the above code is fired in the onLocationChanged event.  The aim is to add a TableRow to a TableLayout for each queued "Exception".  Each row is inserted at position 0.

I've tried everything apart from the correct approach it would appear!

My layout is as follows (resources not used for the time being, but will be once I've sorted out this issue - for all you eagle eyed viewers out there!):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
```

```
   <TableRow android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Dt/Tm"></TextView>            
       <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Spd"></TextView>            
       <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Brg"></TextView>            
       <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Ex"></TextView>            
   </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

There are no exceptions thrown, and if I toast a short message in the for loop, it does appear.

If you need more info, not a problem.

Thanks.

Comment: What LayoutParams are you importing?

Comment: Table row uses TableRow.LayoutParams

Comment: TextView uses android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams

Comment: I have seen other instances where the inappropriate type of LayoutParams were being used, unfortunately this isn't the case here (I THINK.....)

Comment: Ah, I've just checked the code, the LayoutParam classes themselves are fine, however the parameters are not.  The LayoutParam parameters for the TextViews are TableRow.  I'll change this and revert.

Answer (score 1):

```
tbl.addView(tr, 0);
```

I think you need to give that layout params, not 0. Perhaps try this?

```
tbl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that overload.  I have tried it and it hasn't worked unfortunately.  I think I'll change the code to insert on view press, at the moment I'm constantly running in and out of the office to trigger a response!

Answer (score 0):

After all of this, removing the `android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams` qualifier (meaning the layout params for each `TextView` are now `TableRow.LayoutParams`) has fixed the solution.  Why?  I do not know......

Maybe the layout parameters of the TextView have to pertain to the TableRow???!  Scraping here.  Anyway, problem solved :-(